# How to change InfiniteScrollView from horizontal to vertical in android?

Tags: android, scrollview

I am building an android app. I am using this plugin

https://github.com/satansly/InfiniteScrollView

to make a circular scrollview. When I try it, it makes a horizontal scrollview. But I want a vertical one.

It says on the readme `Infinite or Circular scroll view for Android. Allows infinite scrolling in either directions.`.

But there is no documentation on how to change it.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: That code looks like a mess and completely coded for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `getX()` method to `getY()`. Change all `getXVelocity()` to `getYVelocity()`. Change `params.leftMargin` to `params.topMargin`. Also change `MATCH_PARENT` to `WRAP_CONTENT` in constructors of `PSInfiniteScrollView.java` file.

Hope it may work. :)